# Jquery Check if element's title contains specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list like this

```
<ol class="exampleList">
    <li title="Example someTitle">...</li>
    <li title="someTitle2">...</li>
    <li title="someTitle3">...</li>
    <li title="someTitle4">...</li>    
</ol>
```

I want to check if a "li" has title contain "Example" then add class for it. The result should be like this

```
<ol class="exampleList">
    <li title="Example someTitle" class="Added">...</li>
    <li title="someTitle2">...</li>
    <li title="someTitle3">...</li>
    <li title="someTitle4">...</li>    
</ol>
```

Please help me. And sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the attribute contains selector (`*=`)

```
$("li[title*=Example]").addClass("someClass");
```

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!